# How can I add hyperlinks to columns of a table using thymeleaf th:each?

Tags: java, html, html-table, hyperlink, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create hyperlinks for each element in a table generated by thymeleaf.

```java
<tbody>
    <tr th:each="author :${authors}">
        <td th:text="${author.id}"></td>
        <a th:href="@{/authors/{id}(id=${author.id})}">
            <td class="authorLink" th:text="${author.firstName}"></td>
        </a>
        <td th:text="${author.lastName}"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

The code above is giving me an output of the generated hyperlinks outside of the table.

This is a link to the generated html.
https://i.gyazo.com/7dae68eb42cd084b59030e7b17590e5e.png

"linklinklinklink" is the output of the generated hyperlinks. I would like for the 'First Name' column to become hyperlinks.
If anyone can tell me how I can accomplish this that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your `<a>` tag inside the `<td>` cell where you want the link to appear:

```html
<td>
    <a th:href="@{/authors/{id}(id=${author.id})}" 
       th:text="${author.id}"></a>
</td>
```

Note how you can use a `th:text="..."` attribute inside the `<a>` tag, as well, to control the visible text for the link.

In your case, you had a `<a>` tag inside a row, but not part of any cell. This is invalid HTML, so your browser's HTML renderer dumped the links somewhere else (above the table, in this case).

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly the problem. I can't believe I didn't notice the improper HTML syntax.

Comment: You are welcome. Side note: If you have not already done so, I recommend you take the site [tour].